# Is it possible to query from eger loading with where clause?

Tags: php, laravel

```
i got the result from this query:
 $loan=Loan::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->with('customer')->orderByDesc('created_at')->paginate(10);

BUt when i try to retrive same data as:
 $loan = Loan::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->with(['customer'=> function ($query) use($search){
                        $query->where('cname', $search);
                    }])->orderByDesc('created_at')->get();
```

**query return collection with customer.**
**through the error as :attempt ro read property on null after following code on blade view**

```
 @forelse ($loan as $loans)
<tr>

 <td>{{ $loans->customer->cname }}</td>
<tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: the question is not clear, can you please describe your problem. and provide more details what you want to achieve with example.

Comment: is it clear now ?

Comment: filter out all records from Loan model where your sub query(i.e. customer) do not match search criteria. See updated query in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so basically you are querying those customer records which are filtered out from customer table. To fix this filter out all records from Loan model where your sub query(i.e. customer) do not match search criteria.

```
$loan = Loan::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->with(['customer'=> function ($query) use($search){
            $query->where('cname', $search);
        }])
        ->whereHas('customer', function($query) use($search){
            $query->where('cname', $search);
        })
        ->orderByDesc('created_at')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ->whereHas('customer', function()

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

You would still keep ->with('customer')->whereHas('customer',

You keep the ->with( to eagerload, but filter with whereHas